# xcode build project with external libraries that required './configure','make' and 'make install'

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, dependencies

I'm Trying to build an objective-c project which used shared libraries and a dynamic library.

For me to used the external libraries, I had to individually install them with their dependencies using the scripts: './configure' then 'make' then 'make install'.
Then adding them in my project through the 'Link binary with libraries' portion of build phases.

Now on my dev machine, it works fine, but when I build it, and copy the product to a different machine, the plug-in didn't work. So I tried installing the libraries on the vanilla computer and the plug-in only showed up, but still didn't work properly.

So I thought about creating an installer, that will install the libraries to the vanilla computer, before loading my plug-in. But the problem is not all vanilla computers will have the xcode command line tools which would make the 'make' unavailable.

So my questions are, 
- Are the libraries indicated in the link going to be added automatically whenever I make the build?
- Should copying the .a and .dylib files to the vanilla computer suffice to run the plug-in?
- What is the best approach to handle multiple dependencies for this kind of project?

Btw, I'm developing a plug-in with FxPlug, but I think the solution isnt a fxplug specific.

Comment: Just make each dylib and framework a subproject with a custom build script that cd's into it and executes configure and make as necessary.

Comment: @CodaFi I don't seem to understand what you are saying, I am quite new to xcode in general.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I just needed to copy the files along with the built project for it to be read.

So in Xcode, in the target's "Build Phases" I added the "Copy Files" entry by going to Editor> Add Build Phase> Add Copy Files Phase and included the necessary libraries I need.